# MySQL: Выборка продуктов из вложенных категорий

Tags: интернет-магазин, mysql

Если речь идёт об интернет-магазине, самая сложность заключается в выборке продуктов из разных вложенных категорий, и чтобы они не дублировались. Как составить запрос, чтоб он был оптимален?

3 таблицы
items - каталог продуктов;
sections - каталог разделов, составленных по принципу nested sets;
item_section - связь продукт-раздел.

Пока обхожусь

```
SELECT i.* FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT id_item FROM item_section AS t 
LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON s.id = t.id_section) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN items AS i ON i.id = t1.id_item 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

но, очевидно, выбор всех условно 10тысяч изделий для того, чтобы отобразить 50... это, мягко говоря, неоптимально.

как быть?

Comment: Это была болванка запроса. Всё отягощается, когда нужно вставлять условия или сортинг:

SELECT i.* FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT id_item FROM item_section AS t 
LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON s.id = t.id_section) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN items AS i ON i.id = t1.id_item 
WHERE i.name LIKE '%blabla%'
ORDER BY i.name
LIMIT 0, 50

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT i.* FROM items AS i
    WHERE i.name LIKE ...
    ORDER BY...
    LIMIT 0, 50) as si
LEFT JOIN item_section AS t ON t.id = i.id_section
LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON s.id = t.id_section
```

Т.е. сначала ограничиваемся 50-ю item'ами, а потом получаем необходимую информацию об их категориях. Или задача какая, для одной категории 50 продуктов найти?